# NumPy np.linalg.solve give two different solution on different machines

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numeric, numerical-computing

I am studying computer science at the moment. We have the following exercise:
Execute LU decomposition given a matrix A and vector b using NumPy. We had to derive L and U by hand and came up the following result:

```py
eps = 2 ** -52
A = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2+eps,5],[4,6,8]], dtype=np.float64)
L = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [4, 2/eps, 1]], dtype=np.float64)
U = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, eps, 3], [0, 0, 4-6/eps]], dtype=np.float64)
b = np.array([1,0,0], dtype=np.float64)
```

Now we did tried the following code snippet to find the vector x using L and U and also finding x (x_dir) using the original A matrix and b vector. The only problem: one other student and I have a different result for x:

```py
import numpy as np
eps = 2**-52
A = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2+eps,5],[4,6,8]], dtype=np.float64)
L = np.array([[1, 0 ,0], [2, 1, 0], [4, 2/eps ,1]], dtype=np.float64)
U = np.array([[1,1,1],[0,eps,3],[0,0, 4-(6/eps)]], dtype=np.float64)
b = np.array([1,0,0], dtype=np.float64)

y = np.linalg.solve(L, b.T)

'''Ly=b'''
print(y)

'''Ux=y'''
x = np.linalg.solve(U, y)

print(x)

x_dir = np.linalg.solve(A,b.T)

print(x_dir)
```

The result on my computer and the one of a fellow student for x (using LU) was:

```
[ 3.66666667 -2.         -0.66666667]
```

But, the result for this calculation was meant to be:

```
[2.66666667 -1.         −0.66666667]
```

Only he and I have this problem.

We already tried reinstalling NumPy, using different versions of it, using it in venv's and actual virtual machines. We sent the same code snippet to other students and they get the wished result.

What are possible causes for this problem? Based on our knowledge and the given situation we believe it has something to do with the used CPUs or our computers.

- His CPU: AMD RYZEN 7 5825 U with Radeon graphics
- My CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H

Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions what the cause of this problem could be or has encountered similar problems?

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure you wrote the matrices correctly?

Comment: Also, using numpy for this may not work because of the precision you require. 2^-52 is extremely small. There are other packages that can do this symbolically or numerically but to higher precision. I'm not currently at a computer to test anything.

Comment: The solution of your given equations is [(7-4.eps)/(3-2.eps),-2/(3-2.eps),(-2+2.eps)/(3-2.eps)] ... so neither of your stated solutions is correct. If I run your code then xdir is correct (but not what you have written), but I suspect that LU decomposition is not well-conditioned here

Comment: @jared Yes we are, we checked it multiple times with other groups and with the provided solutions by our tutor.

Comment: @fiechdus, if you use a larger value of eps, say 2**(-10), then the solution by the two methods will agree. Your matrices are correct, but LU decomposition is ill-conditioned, because the diagonal element u_22 is too small, leading ultimately to problems with the l_32 and u_33 coefficients. You only have finite precision: doing things like 4-6/eps is likely just to give you -6/eps, for example.

Comment: Note that `2+2**-52` or `2` are the same things in `float64` (sign 0, exponent 1, encoded as 1024), then an implicit 1 (time 2ᵉ=2¹=2), then 52 bits encoding the 2¹/2¹, 2¹/2²,..., 2¹/2⁵² terms. The smallest term being `2**-51`. So all bits 0. In both case. Well borderline for `2+2⁻⁵²`, since it can be rounded with an equal error to `2` or to `2+2⁻⁵¹` (there is nothing in between in float64). Maybe that is the origin of the problem. I am not sure if all CPU make the same choice as "which float64 closest value should represent a value").

Comment: I even question the motive of your teacher here. That `eps=2⁻⁵²` is suspiciously the smallest possible value that "could" be added to 2 (any eps>2⁻⁵² would lead to `2<2+eps`. Any `0<eps<2⁻⁵²` would lead to `2==2+eps` in float64. And `eps=2⁻⁵²` is precisely the only value for which it is unclear (unless there is a norm that I don't know of in float64 specifying that). So, maybe that value is there to see exactly that UB. Or maybe it is because they wanted the smallest possible eps that changes something (it which case, it is a mistake. 2⁻⁵¹ is the smallest possible eps that can be added to 2

Comment: just, 2⁻⁵² can be equivalent to both 0 or 2⁻⁵¹ when added to 2.

Comment: What versions of python are you using? There was an issue i believe with 3.5/3.6 which was fixed in 3.8 if i recall correctly. Use the latest python. Of course ensure everything is correct.

Comment: @Onyambu We used 3.8 or higher as it was requested by our university.

Comment: @lastchance so do I assume correctly that the problem was likely caused by the way our computers calculated this very low numbers? So basically it is machine specific and it simply happened that my computer the the one of the other mentioned student simply could not calculate that specific calculation as precisely as others?

Comment: @fiechtus, I think chrslg is essentially giving you the answer. Your matrices are mathematically correct, but you are suffering from the difficulty in comparing 2 and 2^-52 in magnitude as floats in finite-precision arithmetic. Try print(2,2+eps) at the end of your code. I don’t see why you are reporting xdir incorrectly, though. Direct inversion should give [2.333333,-0.6666667,-0.66666667] for that small a value of eps.

Comment: I suspect these exact numerical difficulties were part of the point of the exercise, to teach about roundoff errors. Have you reached out to the prof?

Comment: @AJBiffl Yes I have. She said that this is a very good example of the LU decomposition being prone to errors but she could not identify the reason for the fact that this only happened on some machines.

Comment: @lastchance Alright, thank you for the reply! I will look into this a bit more to understand it fully.